# Preassigned product category when adding new product in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

Tried a lot of different functions to automatically preselect a specific category when clicking "Add new product" in WooCommerce. But nothing works! I just want a specific category to be preassigned when creating a new product. Is there any simple function to functions.php that do this?

Answer (score 0):

To set the default WooCommerce product category, visit the product category page here: Products > Categories. Once there, hover over the category you want to set as default and click on the ‘Make Default’

might as well get rid of the incredibly unuseful Uncategorized product category. If it’s currently set as the default you will need to set another category as default first. Then simply hover over Uncategorized and click delete.